# How to override vuestic sass variables?

Tags: vue.js, layout, sass

I'm using the vuestic-admin template (https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin) and I need to override some of the sass variables.

But all these variables are located in a seperate node-module (https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-ui).

The main template is importing the variables in: `.../sass/main.scss`

```
@import "~vuestic-ui/src/components/vuestic-sass/global/reset.scss";
@import "~vuestic-ui/src/components/vuestic-sass/global/normalize.scss";
@import "~vuestic-ui/src/components/vuestic-sass/vuestic-styles";
@import './icons/icons.scss';
```

Trying to overide the variables before and after this imports didn't work.

The problem can be reproduced by:

1. clone the vuestic template: `git clone https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-admin.git myproject`
2. install dep: `npm install`
3. start project: `npm run serve`
4. edit `$sidebar-width` in main.scss. default value is 18.75rem. Desired value `$sidebar-width: 10rem`
5. check if the sidebar got smaller